# How to get Related (Asset) Details of Organization

Tags: soql, sql, asset, organization

I am trying to get the Description value of the Asset of an Organization and need a query for that. Is that possible?

When I try query `SELECT AccountId, Product2.Name, Product2.ProductCode, InstallDate, Description FROM Asset`, I get the expected rows but the Description field does not return anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by blanks results? no results (no rows) or the description field in each row is blank even though the data is filled in within the UI?
The later I find hard to believe. How are you querying?
NB: It is a Long Text Field. which is relevant to the Where Clause, you cannot use description in the WhereClause

Comment: What I mean is - when I query "SELECT AccountId, Product2.Name, Product2.ProductCode, InstallDate,Description FROM Asset" - I get other fields - only Description is not fetched

Comment: I would check if the description is actually populated or not and the field i am referencing is same as the where the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to return the Description field.

```
List<Asset> assets = [SELECT Id, Description FROM Asset];
```

If you are getting no rows returned either:

- there is no data or
- you do not have access to the data that is there, or
- your WHERE clause is filter out the data

If the description field is empty then either:

- there is no data in said field or
- you do not have access to the field which does happen even for system admin on some standard fields.

You are returning Rows but no description field, please check your field level access.
Also sometime people create a custom field named Description with less text size and then you may have another field (real stab in the dark there :) )

Here is data returning for me when I use Dev Console:
[image]

Comment: When I query "SELECT AccountId, Product2.Name, Product2.ProductCode, InstallDate,Description FROM Asset" - I get other fields - just not Description

Comment: updated my answer: pls check your field level access

Comment: Is there another custom field called description ?

Comment: any luck with your field-level security
found in SETUP/OBJECT/ASSET/DESCRIPTION when viewing the field at the top
"Set Field-Level Security"

Comment: yes that solved the problem..Thanks for your help